# Is there a simple way to fade in a string char by char using java's Graphics2D objects?

Tags: java, string, fade, graphics2d

I am looking to use a Graphics2D object to draw a string to the screen char by char, having them fade in.

I initially split the string into chars, and drew each individual char but ran into issues with proper spacing between each letter (as each letter is a different amount of pixels.) Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

```
g.drawString(currentLine(j), 250, 770+j*20);
```

vs

```
        for(int i = 0; i < currentLine(j).length(); i++) {
            String chr = new StringBuilder().append("").append(currentLine(j).charAt(i)).toString();
            g.drawString(chr, 250+i*10, 770+j*20);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "GlyphVector" to get text's Width & Height.

```
String testString = "A";
GlyphVector gv = g.getFont().createGlyphVector(g.getFontRenderContext(), testString);
Rectangle textBound = gv.getOutline().getBounds();
double textHeight = textBound.getHeight();
double textWidth = textBound.getWidth();
```